# How I can print PHP variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to print my PHP variable:

```
<?php
    $section= $_GET['section'];
    $author = $_GET['author'];
?>
<html>
<!--Some HTML page's elements-->
</html>
```

And my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var SECTION = '<?php echo $section;?>';
alert('My section is: ' + SECTION);
var AUTHOR = '<?php echo $author;?>';
alert('Current author is: ' + AUTHOR);
});
```

But only I get in alert's message: 'My section is: ' + `<?php echo $section;?>`'

Comment: PHP is executed on the server. JavaScript is executed in the browser. You need some mechanism to request the server to evaluate the PHP for you. The typical answer is AJAX.

Comment: where does your js run?

Comment: php is not executed in `.js` files

Comment: Add your javascript to your PHP page and not in an external js file and your PHP should execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this all a single page

test.php?section=5&author=james

test.php

```
<?php
    $section= $_GET['section'];
    $author = $_GET['author'];
?>
<html>
<!--Some HTML page's elements-->
</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var SECTION = '<?php echo $section;?>';
        alert('My section is: ' + SECTION);
        var AUTHOR = '<?php echo $author;?>';
        alert('Current author is: ' + AUTHOR);
        });
</script>
```

works fine

Comment: Yes! But  If I want to use another js-file is in another folder?

Comment: You can set javascript variables in the php file, and then use the external js files that access those variables.  In your question, just set the two variables (SECTION and AUTHOR), and then use those in the external js file if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Rob will set your JS variables from PHP, but also makes you vulnerable to Javascript injection - **Do not** use this method as is.

If you want to set JS variables from within PHP, and those variables should be set by the user - simply set them from within JS, or do a very strict input filtering.